# API Design; action endpoints

Tags: rest, api, http

Let's say I have a devices which will connect to a server and register/transfer data through an API.

I understand that you would have things like:

```
GET: api/devices
GET: api/devices/:id
POST api/devices
DELETE: api/devices/:id
```

Those are examples of typical CRUD endpoints.

But where would I add endpoints for checking if this device is allowed to connect with it's factory ID?

I was thinking of always passing a post field with an API key in the form of a device ID, but that would mess with the HTTP verbs.

So I think the best way is to add a parameter like this:

```
GET: api/devices/:id?id=something
```

But that would become redundant with this endpoint.

So the question is; how would I successfully identify my own devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're simply looking for a way to do authentication. Take a look at the `Authorization` header and the various authentication schemes for it. If existing authentication schemes don't fit your needs, you can also extend it with your own. Common ones are `Basic`, `Digest` and `Bearer`. An example of a vendor-extension is `AWS`.

Comment: Yes, essentially it boils down to that. I guess I figured it was a bit different because I wasn't looking for a typical API Key/secret system because I program the clients myself. But thanks, I'll have a look at those!

Comment: @NathanPrins even if you're designing the clients yourself, chances are they you're gonna run into similar patterns that someone else already has ran into ;) re-using existing standards for this stuff might give you additional nice benefits too, such as having to write less code or relying on someone else's documentation.

Comment: Yes I'm cognizant of that, that's half the work of a programmer haha. But in this case most API's require you to register an App and you'll receive a secret and you use both the appname and the secret to authenticate. But in this case I don't want people to have to register their own device, but I want the devices to hold a certain key from 'factory' which shows that they are actually legit clients and not third party.. That isn't fixed with Basic, Digest etc. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @NathanPrins. Well if there's some 'factory key', and you can hash this key well so it becomes unguessable, you can probably just use it as-is as a Bearer token. Using Bearer token doens't require the full OAuth2 flow.

Comment: Okay great! I was thinking of generating a key automatically when programming the device and then storing the generated keys in a table on the server for allowed keys. This way each device is unique and brute forcing one key doesn't give access to every device.

Comment: That makes sense @NathanPrins